# exam math from data using OLEDB

Tags: c#, ms-access, oledb, windows-forms-designer, sqldatareader

I'm trying to make an exam form. It is suppose to take a question from different tables in my file, and by clicking `Q1button` to check the answer and print a suitable message. In addition, it is suppose to ask the user 8 questions, and update the answer (if it was answered correctly) in `counterCorrectAns`. By clicking `Q1button` it is updating the textboxes in random question from specific table.

```
private int randomQues=0,number=1,counterCorrectAns=0;
private string correctAns = "";

void SetQues1Box(int number)
{
    string whatTake="",fromWhere="",autoNum="";

    from.Text =""+ number;
    to.Text = "" + 8;
    string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Users\\hodaya\\Desktop\\Project.accdb";

    using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
    {
        switch (number)
        {
            case 1: whatTake = "misHQueA, mishAnsA"; fromWhere = "mishvaotA"; autoNum = "mishAnum"; break;
            case 2: whatTake = "misHQueB, mishAnsB"; fromWhere = "mishvaotB"; autoNum = "mishBnum"; break;

        }
        string sql = "SELECT " + whatTake + " FROM " + fromWhere + " WHERE " + autoNum + "=?";

        Random r = new Random();
        randomQues=r.Next(1, 25);
        using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(sql, connection))
        {
            connection.Open();
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue(autoNum, randomQues);
            OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            reader.Read();
            q1Box.Text = reader.GetString(0);
            correctAns = ("" + reader.GetInt32(1));
            connection.Close();
    //**// }
        }
    }
}

private void Q1Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string exp;

    if (number <= 8)
    {
        if (ans1Box.Text == correctAns)
        {
            counterCorrectAns++;
            exp = "correct answer";
        }
        else
            exp = "'wrong answer";
        MessageBox.Show(exp);
        number = number + 1;
        SetQues1Box(number);
    }
    else
    {
        if (counterCorrectAns >= 4)
            MessageBox.Show("your great");
        else
            MessageBox.Show("you are need more practice");
        this.Close();
    }

}
```

The error that I get :`COM object that has been separated from its underlying RCW cannot be used.` in the line with //**// in its beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The using already manage the `connection.close()`.

On MSDN documentation, they don't put `connection.close()` if they wrap their code in using instruction.

What is happening is that the using tries to close a connection that you already closed.

However, `reader` should be closed before the end of the using block